# Malloc in C, Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

Why `malloc` allocate 6 bytes `char` types, but I need 2 bytes.
If I allocate 1 byte, he allocate 5 bytes.
I don't understand why.

```
#include "stdlib.h"

int     main()
{
  char *lin = malloc(2);
  lin[0] = 'a';
  lin[1] = 'b';
  char *line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
  line[0] = 'z';
  line[1] = 'b';

  printf("lin = %s\nline = %s\n", lin, line);

  get_next_line(fd, line);
  return (0);
}
```

That shows that the console

```
lin = ab¤¤¤¤
line = zb¤¤¤¤
```

Comment: There are no `'\0'` string terminators, so your code exhibits *undefined behaviour*. To do that, you must allocate (at least) one more byte of memory and write the terminators yourself.

Comment: Your both `lin` and `line` are not null-terminated, last character of a string should be '`\0'` (Index 1 in your case). Otherwise printing a string with printf prints everything until `'\0'` which is UB.

Comment: Anyway, the memory manager is not required to be able to allocate *any* odd size, so when asking for 1 byte, or 13 bytes, the actual size might be rounded up to some larger value (like 8 or 16 bytes, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, a [ASCII](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange) character string is represented as a sequence of nonzero bytes followed by a byte with value zero, see [Null-terminated byte strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). The string `"ab"` is represented as an array that holds the values `0x61, 0x62, 0x00`.

Example:

```
string:     'a'  | 'b'  |
memory:     0x61 | 0x62 | 0x00
```

Quick fix:

```
char *lin = malloc(3); // allocate one more char
lin[0] = 'a';
lin[1] = 'b';
lin[2] = '\0';         // terminate the string
```

In your case, `malloc` is not allocating 6 bytes, `printf` is just printing pseudo random "garbage" because your string is not zero-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

A valid C string is a zero-terminated char array.

If you have a char array **without** a zero-termination it is **not** a string and it is illegal to use it with `printf` and format specifier `%s`

To add the zero-termination to a char array do:

```
someCharArray[someIndex] = '\0';
```

So for your code do two things:

1) allocate 1 more byte so that you have room for the zero-termination

2) add the zero-termination

Like:

```
#include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{
  char *lin = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
  lin[0] = 'a';
  lin[1] = 'b';
  lin[2] = '\0';

 char *line = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
 line[0] = 'z';
 line[1] = 'b';
 line[2] = '\0';

  printf("lin = %s\nline = %s\n", lin, line);

  get_next_line(fd, line);
  return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why malloc allocate 6 bytes char types, but i need 2 bytes. If i allocate 1 bytes, he allocate 5 bytes.

`malloc` is *not* allocating too much memory, you're just accessing memory you didn't allocate.

To prevent accessing that memory, `printf` needs to know where your strings end. In C, this is usually done by adding a [null-character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) `'\0'` at the end of the string, like this:

```
char *line = malloc(3); // allocate one more byte to store the null-character
line[0] = 'a';
line[1] = 'b';
line[2] = '\0'; // insert the null-character to mark the end of the string

printf("line = %s\n", line);
```

Now `printf` knows where the string `line` ends, and it stops reading from memory at that point, and so doesn't read the garbage values `¤¤¤¤` that happened to be in memory after the string.

<sub>Note that most C library functions expect the strings passed to them to be null-terminated, so you should always null-terminate your strings by default (unless you pass the size by some other means).</sub>